# How to safely trigger an event?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I am not sure whether is this the way to trigger an event in C#:

```
public event EventHandler<ActionEventArgs> ActionDataReceived;

public void showLog(string logMessage)
{
   ActionDataReceived(this, new ActionEventArgs(logMessage));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The safe way is to take a copy of the handler and raise that instead i.e.

```
var handler = ActionDataReceived;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, new ActionEventArgs(logMessage));
}
```

This will mitigate the race condition that could lead to the event being unassigned before you attempt to raise it.

---

As @EricLippert has pointed out this **does not** cover the scenario where the internal state of the handler is changed *after* the assignment has occurred.

Comment: I assure you that it does not mitigate **any** race condition; it only mitigates the race condition whereby the event is changed to null after it is checked for nullity. For example, suppose we have the following race between threads Alpha and Bravo: Alpha copies the delegate into handler and checks it for nullity. Then Bravo removes method M from the event handler list and *destroys state that M needs to operate correctly* assuming incorrectly that M will never be called again because it is no longer a handler. Then Alpha invokes M, which blows up.

Comment: This pattern does not mitigate that race at all; if that is the situation you are in then you have to find some other way to mitigate the race. Generally the best thing to do is: if it hurts when you do that, don't do that. A handler in a multi-threaded program should *always* be in a state where it can be safely called *regardless of whether it is currently registered as a handler or not*.

Comment: @EricLippert By *any* race condition I was referring to any sort of scenario where the event could being unassigned/changed. However, from what you're saying the handler can still be changed? It was my understanding that once you took a copy of the handler it would execute as is (regardless if it is then subsequently changed before you invoke).

Comment: Exactly; the handler executes *the copy*, and *the original could be changing*, which means that a handler that is now "stale" can execute after you think that it will not execute again.

Comment: @EricLippert ah...I didn't quite see what the problem with that scenario was at first, can see now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = ActionDataReceived;
if (temp != null)
      temp();
```

You may refer to [this post of Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx) for detailed explanation.